# Is there a way to have multiple "bootable images" on a USB stick and choose between them?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Since my little double-sided USB key (micro and USB-A) has 16GB (it's also got some tiny Android files), I was wondering how to manage multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiBoot USB is an installer with which one can install multiple
Live Linux or Windows distros to a single USB drive, pendrive or
flash drive, and be able to boot from it and select the one to boot
into.

See the article
[5 Apps to Create Multiboot USB – Linux & Windows ISOs Supported](https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso)
for a review of five utilities that can create such a USB device:

- SARDU MultiBoot USB and DVD Creator
- MultiBootUSB
- MultiSystem
- YUMI (Your Universal MultBoot Installer)
- WinSetupFromUSB.